# Creating a consolidated set of pairs on Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, match, consolidation

I am working with an Excel file having import and export data between different countries for various shipping products, which looks pretty much like this:

[image: Raw data]

The goal is to create a consolidated state pair that have a trade relation between them. So the final list for the above example should look something like this:

[image: Result goal]

What would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: How do you arrive at 4 for Japan/China? Is this a bi-directional count?

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,E4,B:B,F4)+COUNTIFS(A:A,F4,B:B,E4)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So assume your data is in a&b in the first screenshot, put this formula in column c
`=a1&b1` then hit enter, then drag the bottom right hand corner down so the formula works for all cells in that column. Then copy the column and paste it as values.

Then in column d, use the formula =countifs(c:c,c1) and drag it down in the same way. Now paste column d as values.

Finally, on the data tab, remove duplicates based on column c and then delete column c.

Comment: It would be easier to do that with a pivot table, but it does not produce what the question is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this really easy with Pivot Tables. Just take Field `Importing Country` into rows section and also values section (make sure it's counting) and field `Exporting Country`to rows section.

Choose Tabular design, deactivate subtotals and activate Repeat labels. This is what you get:

[image]

Comment: I thought so, too, but the OP wants to count the relationships, so it's 3x Japan/China plus 1 in reverse for China/Japan = 4 for any relationship count between China and Japan.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and O365

- Sort each row horizontally
- Group by the two resultant country rows, aggregating by Count

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Importing Country", type text}, {"Exporting Country", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Country", each List.Sort({[Importing Country],[Exporting Country]})),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Importing Country", "Exporting Country"}),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Country", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Extracted Values", "Country", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Country.1", "Country.2"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Country.1", type text}, {"Country.2", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Country.1", "Country.2"}, {{"Occurrences", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]